# Slack > Applescript/JS on new DM?

Tags: javascript, applescript, nsapplescript

I'm trying to do some automation on new slack DM, (I'm using Applescript with some JS code),

I can read the numbers of unread message with this AppleScript

```
tell application "Safari"
    
    set unreadmessage to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('p-channel_sidebar__badge c-mention_badge c-mention_badge--black')[0].innerHTML;" in tab 2 of window 1
    
end tell
```

But I can't tell who that message was sent from and how to action it and reply to it

-- Slack API is not an option for me since disabled by my organisation

[image]

Comment: That looks like HTML - not AppleScript.

Comment: yes I meant using JS through applescript to interfact with the HTML

Comment: You might have better luck explaining _exactly_ what you are trying to do - some HTML markup that just describes a badge icon doesn’t help much.  Have you looked at using the Slack (Web) API?

Comment: fair enough, I just updated my post, unfortunatly Slack API is disabled by my organisation